# Dropdown arrow failure IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

When loading my website with IE the select drop down looks like this:

[image]

Does anybody know how I can remove the centered drop down arrows? In Chrome, Safari, Firefox they are not visible...

Here The code:

```
<div class="col-md mb-3">
<select class="common_selector intervention form-control form-control-sm border-secondary" id="common_selector_intervention">
<option value="">Intervention</option>
<?php echo filter_intervention($pdo_connect); ?>
</select>
</div>
```

I am using Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Which version of IE browser version and Bootstraps version are you using?  I have created a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/btzm9427/) using Bootstrap 4.3.1 version, it seems that everything works well in IE browser, you could create a new page to test it. Besides, please check the CSS style, whether there has other CSS style, which might be causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a pseudo-element for the dropdown arrow on IE:

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

Hope it helps..